# Not able to receive notification on iOS

Tags: flutter, signals, onesignal

Flutter version: 3.7.12
onesignal_flutter 3.5.1
I am also getting same warnings

```
2023-04-27 12:08:58.568676+0530 Runner[17201:195467] WARNING: OneSignal has detected that your application delegate implements a deprecated method (application:didReceiveLocalNotification:). Please note that this method has been officially deprecated and the OneSignal SDK will no longer call it. You should use UNUserNotificationCenter instead
```

Also i am not able to receive any notification on iOS, is this warning is responsible for not receiving any notification.
When i send a push notification to iOS devices, the device is getting registered with 'APNs BAD DEVICE TOKEN' along with this no notification is received on iOS simulator.
Any possible solution for this issue?

Comment: The warning tells you exactly where the issue is. It would be helpful if you added more context of your code to what you are facing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.